# Agora.io security token generated invalid (Golang)

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

Having problem getting security token generated from my server to work properly. I modified the basicLive.js of the demo in AgoraWebSDK-NG to work with my server. I'm using the Golang api provided by Agora to generate the token. Some information:

```
AppID: ---
App Certificate: ---
channel name: liveshow10
uid: 51495 (I assume Agora does not care about this as long as it is uint32)
token expiration seconds: 3600
generated token: 006cb08a5a2ddc049f79f29d9b52e5909b0IABKKxbI64sFWnkyEICQrL+0DeTsrN9ckKMkDj/oir36aV+tq536WyGcIgCHHmUFHNv6XgQAAQCsl/leAgCsl/leAwCsl/leBACsl/le
```

But I'm getting bunch of error in the console. I think it boils down to an authorization error the token generated somehow is invalid. Below is the browser console and thanks for any help:

[image]

Comment: if you hardcode the token, does it give you an error? Are you implementing the "token-will-expire" and "did-expire" callbacks?

Comment: Are you using String or int UID?

Comment: I'm using uint32 UID. I tried once again generating token with RtcTokenBuilderSample.py in the python example. And I ran the basicLive demo supplying the generated token. Same error still. Agora server still complains about invalid token.

Comment: Tried again with String. Same error:"AgoraRTCError CAN_NOT_GET_GATEWAY_SERVER: invalid token, authorized failed". Btw, hardcoding the token didn't help either, same error.

Comment: I just tested that AppId without the Token and it connects without issue (https://digitallysavvy.github.io/group-video-chat/) and (https://webdemo.agora.io/agora-web-showcase/examples/Agora-Web-Tutorial-1to1-Web). This means the tokens are not setup correctly on your account, so no token will work. can you send me an email hermes@agora.io

Answer (score 11):

For anyone following along, the issue was related to UID. In the above code the token is generate specifically for UID `51495` but in the Agora Demo, the JoinChannel method passes `null` as the UID value which tells the SDK to generate its own UID for that user.

When attempting to join a channel with a different UID than the one used to generate the token, you will receive an error.

If you want to generate a token that can be used by any user, you need to set the UID to 0 in the token generation, and then you can use any UID join the channel with this token.

> *Update:* The UID 0 detail can be found in the Token Server API reference within the UID parameter description [docs.agora.io/en/video/token_server#api-reference](https://docs.agora.io/en/video/token_server#api-reference)

Comment: Wow... I cant believe i made such a silly mistake.... The UID was the first cause of my problem and then secondly, I had not enabled the app certificates. After i did the above mentioned, it worked very well.

Thank you so much for this answer!

Comment: I felt UID was very optional like in the token generated from Agora console. Your answer helped me with my Agora flutter + PHP backend

Comment: @Eaweb how were you able to generate token from the backend, anytime I generate token on the backend and try to use it on the client (almost immediately), I get token expired

Comment: How are you calculating expiration time? Take a look at my guide on token generation using nodejs https://www.agora.io/en/blog/how-to-build-a-token-server-for-agora-applications-using-nodejs/

Comment: Hi @Temi'Topsy'Bello make sure you are joining the channel with the same UID you used for generating the token on the backend. It will be worth checking the expiry time too.

Comment: @Hermes, ' If you want to generate a token that can be used by any user, you need to set the UID to 0 in the token generation, and then you can use any UID join the channel with this token.'- can you tell  where it is said in the Agora doc ?

Comment: It’s in the Token Server API reference within the UID parameter description https://docs.agora.io/en/video/token_server#api-reference